# ImportError: cannot import name 'array' from 'numpy.core' (unknown location)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm getting this error all of a sudden (everything worked fine earlier today)

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'array' from 'numpy.core' (unknown location)
```

Here is the culprit:

```
import functools
import operator
import warnings

from numpy.core import (
    array, asarray, zeros, empty, empty_like, intc, single, double,
    csingle, cdouble, inexact, complexfloating, newaxis, all, Inf, dot,
    add, multiply, sqrt, fastCopyAndTranspose, sum, isfinite,
    finfo, errstate, geterrobj, moveaxis, amin, amax, product, abs,
    atleast_2d, intp, asanyarray, object_, matmul,
    swapaxes, divide, count_nonzero, isnan
)
from numpy.core.multiarray import normalize_axis_index
from numpy.core.overrides import set_module
from numpy.core import overrides
from numpy.lib.twodim_base import triu, eye
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
```

All I do it select this and hit F9:

```
import numpy as np
```

I uninstalled and re-installed numpy.  I Googled for a solution but didn't find much.  Anyone here come across this before?  Any thoughts on what to do?  Thanks.

Comment: Want to show the code that's triggering that?

Comment: You probably need to install `numpy` first

Comment: And please make sure you're using the version of Python you're expecting. If you have multiple Python versions installed, or if you're using conda and have multiple environments, you may be running this code in a context that is different from the one where you installed numpy.

Comment: You shouldn't import things and pollute your namespace unless you know you need them.

Comment: I have Anaconda (64-bit) and Python 3.7.  That's it.

Comment: Right, so have you made sure you are in the right Anaconda environment? When you type `conda list` in the same  environment as the one you're running your Python script from, does it show numpy in the list?

Comment: Niayesh Isky has given good advice. See the [conda documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

you may need to `import numpy` first then use `from numpy import ()`

Comment: No, that should generally work. However, @ryguy72, it is worth a try to see if `import numpy` by itself works.

Comment: Nope, import numpy throws the same error.  So weird.  Everything was working fine a few hours ago.  I don't know what could have changed.  Something changed, apparently.  No idea what though.

Comment: I uninstalled Python3.6 and then installed Python3.7.  Everything works fine now.